# jQuery scroll bootstrap panel to top of screen is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small jquery script that is not working & I am not sure why

Script:

```
$('#accordion-data-parent-001, #accordion-data-parent-002').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   var id = $(e.target).prev().find("[id]")[0].id;
   navigateToElement(id);
})

function navigateToElement(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top -90
    }, 100);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-data-parent-001">
            <div class="panel panel-default"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-data-parent-001, #accordion-data-parent-002" href="#collapse-37" class="staff">
                <div class="panel-heading" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/barak-obama.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"> President Barak Obama </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse-37" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-data-parent-002">
            <div class="panel panel-default"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-data-parent-001, #accordion-data-parent-002" href="#collapse-45" class="staff">
                <div class="panel-heading" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"> <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/clint-eastwood.jpg" alt="" /> </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"> A new guy </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse-45" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It is supposed to scroll the current panel to the top of the screen, but I cannot seem to get it working.